# Querying Firebase using Swift 3 and Xcode 8

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

We are trying to read specific data sets from Firebase and the current solution we have is this:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("messages")

func retrieveMessageAttributes() {
    ref.queryOrderedByKey().queryEqual(toValue: "uniqueFirebaseID").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot)
        for item in snapshot.children {
            let data = (item as! FIRDataSnapshot).value! as! NSDictionary
            print("*********************")
            print((data["text"])!)
        }
    })
```

This prints all of the data for the specific set in the console, however it seems strange to have to retrieve data, convert it to a hash, and then read specific values.

So we were wondering if anyone else has an alternative method, or ORM, which is simpler and cleaner.

Comment: More idiomatic is to listen to `.childAdded` (and other child events) and immediately update the user interface.